# How do I get "hello world" script to run from the command line in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I can not get pass this error message.

Thanks

```
The term 'power-date.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify t
hat the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:15
+ power-date.ps1 <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (power-date.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFound 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: do you have a `.ps1` file called `power-date.ps1`?

Comment: yes I do at different location.  Just to make sure I can find it from the command line because windows does not like white spaces

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'windows does not like white spaces'. Windows handles whitespace in commands without problems and has done so for a very long time.

Answer (score 5):

PowerShell will not run scripts in the current directory unless you prefix them with `.\` e.g.:

```
.\power-date.ps1
```

This is a security feature that prevents someone from dropping a script called dir or ls into a directory the hacker can access and that the user is often in.  The hacker's intention being that when the user executes `dir`, the fake dir.ps1 wwould be invoked unknownst to the user.  This security feature prevents this sort of attack.  If the user wants to invoke the script dir.ps1, they have to explicitly reference it by path e.g. `.\dir.ps1`